# Pass Files to Node Server

Tags: reactjs, file-upload, form-data

Im having this function in my react app, what is does is sending a file to the server and the server save it to the declared dir.

```
      const handleUploadfile = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        const data = new FormData();
        data.append('file',file );

        fetch("http://localhost:4000/upload", {
             method: 'POST',
             body: data
        }).then((response) => console.log(response))

      }
```

heres the code in the node server handling the request above

```
app.post("/upload", (req, res) => {
  const newpath = "./files/";
  const file = req.files.file;
  const filename = file.name;

  file.mv(`${newpath}${filename}`, (err) => {
    if (err) {
      res.status(500).send({ message: "File upload failed", code: 200 });
    }
    res.status(200).send({ message: "File Uploaded", code: 200 });
  });
});
```

The upload is working well, but what i want to know is, am i able to include some data like a string directory for each uploaded file something like that.

BTW im using express-uploadfile middleware so i can access the files.

Comment: You can call the file that you use what ever you want.. 

The path to file must be a real path fou you to access the file

Comment: @yanirmidler the code is succesfully working accessing the file in node and saving it to new directory... 

what i want to know is how to add some string like "./files/folder1/" and use it as the value of new path.. 

because in the current state of the code newpath variable is fixed and i want it to be dynamic

Answer (score 0):

If you want to upload another filed in your request you simply need to call append on your FormData object.

```
    const data = new FormData();
    data.append('file',file );
    data.append('string','some string');
```

Then read it on the server

```
const string = req.body.string;
```

Comment: tried this, apparently i dont have anything inside body this way, dunno what i did wrong,

But the fix or solution i found was to append another document using Blob then read the blob data on the server which the strings written on.